# netbeans - list of included files

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-plugins

Exist any plugin or settings for Netbeans to show list of included files in actual file? Something like in Dreamweaver - under opened files tab is another tab with included php, js, css and you can "fast switch" to this file.

Comment: I really need an answer to this question. this simple 'missing' feature has prevented me from using netbeans. so pls anyone help !!!